# Why is append() adding markup multiple times as opposed to just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery's append() and the forEach() function to map through an array of objects, displaying the data to a slideshow. Although the array has one object in it, the resulting markup has extra data, essentially the append() method is appending the same markup 2x or more times.

I've tried to remove the markup and instead replace it with "Hello World" (no tags) and it renders correctly. However, when I input "Hello World", it will be appending 3 times as opposed to once. I've console.logged the array to ensure that it only contains one object before and during the forEach() method and can confirm that there is only one element in the array, therefore this is an issue with append()

```
$.getJSON(
            `${window.location.origin}/public/js/config/shopCards.json`,
            function(res) {
                var featuredItems = res.filter(function(item) {
                    return item.isFeatured;
                });

                if (featuredItems.length === 0) {
                    $('.featured-items').empty();
                    return;
                }

                console.log(featuredItems, featuredItems);

                featuredItems.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    $('.siema-home').append(`       
        <div class="card card-shop home-card ${
                        item.isExclusive ? 'exclusive' : ''
                    } ${item.isOnSale ? 'sale' : ''} ${item.isFeatured ? 'featured' : ''} ${item.isSemiExclusive ? 'semiExclusive' : ''}" data-id=${item.id}>
          <div style="position: relative">
            <img src=${
                                item.thumbnailURL
                            } class="card-img-top" alt=${item.projectName} draggable="false"/>
            <div class="card-more-details">
              <p class="helper-text">Click For More Details</p>
              ${
                                    item.isExclusive
                                        ? '<span class="badge badge-warning mb-2">Exclusive Build</span>'
                                        : ''
                                }
              ${
                                    item.isSemiExclusive
                                        ? '<span class="badge badge-danger mb-2">Semi-Exclusive Build</span>'
                                        : ''
                                }
              ${
                                    item.isOnSale
                                        ? '<span class="badge badge-success mb-2">On Sale</span>'
                                        : ''
                                }
              ${
                                    item.isFeatured
                                        ? '<span class="badge badge-info mb-2">Featured</span>'
                                        : ''
                                }
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body card-shop-body">
            <div>
              <h5 class="card-title-shop text-center">
                ${item.projectName}
              </h5>

              <p class="card-price text-center">$${item.price}</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>`);
                });
```

I expect to only see one "shop-card" in the slider.

The actual output is 3 cards in the slider.

Debug information: [Chrome w/ Dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFuD1.png)

Full index.html available [here](https://hastebin.com/obuhoqikin.xml) (for further scrutiny)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193799/discussion-on-question-by-shaun-chander-why-is-append-adding-markup-multiple-t).

Answer (score 0):

So after tedious work and testing, I found out that the issue was actually with the slider, Siema, which actually duplicates the markup and adds it back into the `siema-home` div. Another issue was with using `width: 100%` with Siema, which causes the slider to break and display the extra-slides it created side-by-side with the markup appended by the `append()` function.

TLDR: This was an issue with the slider and the fix was to edit the width from 100% to a smaller value or used a definite pixel value.